# Stop Jbutton from making a change if already clicked

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

Novice programmer here trying to make a tic tac toe GUI game. I'm stuck with my program though. I'm not sure how to place a check on hitting the same square twice. I was thinking an if statement inside my actionListener that said

```
if(button clicked = True)
{    
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((null, "ERROR", "Button already used. 
     Please hit again to change back", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
     // STOP something along those lines
}
else 
{
     //Do nothing
}
```

would work but I can't get the program to work properly. I tried newTurn.getmodel().isPressed() and that didn't work and now with my current code the program outputs the error message after each move and the changes still appear on the board. Here's my code for this method. Any help is appreciated.

```
private class buttonListener implements ActionListener
{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {   
        JButton newTurn = (JButton)e.getSource(); //get the particular button that was clicked
        if(switchMove%2 == 0)
            newTurn.setText("X");
        else
            newTurn.setText("O");

        if(newTurn.isEnabled())
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR", "Button already used. Please hit again to change back", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        if(checkForWin() == true)
        {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Game Over.");
            resetButtons();
        }

        switchMove++;
    }
```

switch move is just an int set to 0 so evens are X and O's are odd. My if (newTurn.isEnabled()) is my issue

Comment: Use a `JToggleButton` or disable the button from further interaction

Answer (score 0):

Here is my resolved code.

```
    public void resetButtons()
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
    {
        buttons[i].setText("");
        buttons[i].setEnabled(true);
    }


}

private class buttonListener implements ActionListener
{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {   
        JButton newTurn = (JButton)e.getSource(); 
        if(switchMove%2 == 0)
            newTurn.setText("X");
        else
            newTurn.setText("O");

        if(newTurn.isEnabled())
            newTurn.setEnabled(false);

        if(checkForWin() == true)
        {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Game Over.");
            resetButtons();
        }

        switchMove++;
    }
```

In the actionPerformed() method I set the buttons to setEnabled(false) after a button was clicked. Then when a game is over the buttons that were previously disabled will be set to setEnabled(true) via the resetButtons method.